# JS:How to make the box to jump again only after the previous jump is done

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a script which makes the grey box jump when the page is clicked. But when the box is still jumping, the jump function still can be activated if I click the page. If I click the page repeatedly, the box is like fidgeting in the air. How can I fix it? I want to allow the box to jump again only after the previous jump is done.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    html, body {
      position:fixed;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      margin:0;
    }    
  </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="Floor"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
let up = false;
let jumping = false;

function box(x, y, width, height, jHeight) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.jHeight = jHeight;

  boxID = document.getElementById('box');
  boxID.style.bottom = y + 'px';
  boxID.style.left = x + 'px';
  boxID.style.width = width + 'px';
  boxID.style.height = height + 'px';
  boxID.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
  boxID.style.position = 'fixed';   
}

function Floor(x, y, width, height) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;

  FloorID = document.getElementById('Floor');
  FloorID.style.bottom = y + 'px';
  FloorID.style.left = x + 'px';
  FloorID.style.width = width + '%';
  FloorID.style.height = height + 'px';
  FloorID.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  FloorID.style.position = 'fixed';
}

function setup() {
  obj = new box(20, 200, 40, 40, 300);
  Ground = new Floor(0, 0, 100, 200);
}

function jump(up, jumping) {
  if(up && (obj.y<obj.jHeight)) {
    jumping = true;
    obj.y+=5;
    boxID.style.bottom = obj.y +'px';
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        jump(up, jumping);
    }, 15);
  } else if (up) {
    jumping = true;
    up = false;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        jump(up, jumping);
    },15);
  } else if (!up && (obj.y>Ground.height)) {
    jumping = true;
    obj.y-=5;
    boxID.style.bottom = obj.y +'px';
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        jump(up, jumping);
    },15);
  } else if (obj.y == Ground.height) {
    jumping = false;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  setup();

  document.addEventListener("click",function() {
    if (jumping == false) {
      jump(true, true);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let up = false;
let jumping = false;
function box(x, y, width, height, jHeight){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.jHeight = jHeight;

boxID = document.getElementById('box');
boxID.style.bottom = y + 'px';
boxID.style.left = x + 'px';
boxID.style.width = width + 'px';
boxID.style.height = height + 'px';
boxID.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
boxID.style.position = 'fixed'; 
}

function Floor(x, y, width, height){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;

FloorID = document.getElementById('Floor');
FloorID.style.bottom = y + 'px';
FloorID.style.left = x + 'px';
FloorID.style.width = width + '%';
FloorID.style.height = height + 'px';
FloorID.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
FloorID.style.position = 'fixed';
}

function setup(){
obj = new box(20, 200, 40, 40, 300);
Ground = new Floor(0, 0, 100, 200);
}

function jump(up, jum){
if(up && (obj.y<obj.jHeight)){
    jum = true;
    obj.y+=2;
    boxID.style.bottom = obj.y +'px';
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        jump(up, jum);
    },15
    );
}else if (up){
    jum = true;
    up = false;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        jump(up, jum);
    },15
    );
}else if (!up && (obj.y>Ground.height)){
    jum = true;
    obj.y-=2;
    boxID.style.bottom = obj.y +'px';
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        jump(up, jum);
    },15
    );
}else if (obj.y == Ground.height){
    jum = false;
}
jumping = jum
}


window.onload = function() {
    setup();

    document.addEventListener("click",function(){
                if(jumping == false){
                    jump(true, true);
                }
            }
        );
};
```

I assume you're handling it right , I only added jumping = jum for the jump function and changed the name of the function variables because it's not modifying the jumping global variable.In fact what I think is actually happening when you pass the variable name as "jumping" and your global variable name is with the same name , it ignores it and uses it's own local variable that's why this condition below is always true when I tested it:

```
 if(jumping == false){
           jump(true, true);
    }
```

I changed the speed just for testing

Answer (score 0):

this is happen because you using defferent jumping variable. global jumping different with inner jumping in jump function. try to not pass jumping to jump function. or change it to other name variable

```
function jump(up, unused){ //unused param unused
console.log(jumping);
if(up && (obj.y<obj.jHeight)){
jumping = true;
obj.y+=5;
boxID.style.bottom = obj.y +'px';
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    jump(up, jumping);
},15
);
}else if (up){
jumping = true;
up = false;
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    jump(up, jumping);
},15
);
}else if (!up && (obj.y>Ground.height)){
jumping = true;
obj.y-=5;
boxID.style.bottom = obj.y +'px';
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    jump(up, jumping);
},15
);
}else if (obj.y == Ground.height){
jumping = false;
}
}
```